# How bootstrap 5 wp-navwalker to have a accordion menu instead of dropdown?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-5, accordion, wp-nav-walker

I'm actually having trouble getting the bootstrap accordion to work in the dropdown menu with the navwalker. I googled a lot and also found some threads on github, but they are several years old and depend on bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 2. Like this one here: [Trying to convert bootstrap wp-navwalker to have a accordion menu instead of dropdwn](https://gist.github.com/cinghaman/008e4874ed4ceb33fd3f)

I want create like this menu([codepen](https://www.codeply.com/go/F8iQy0MeLa)) by navwalkerbootstrap5 in wordpress.

Can anyone help me here or have a solution for a working accordion inside a bootstrap5 navwalker dropdown menu.

this is file wp-bootstrap-navwalker

```
<?php
```

/**

- WP Bootstrap Navwalker
- 
- @package WP-Bootstrap-Navwalker
- 
- @wordpress-plugin
- Plugin Name: WP Bootstrap Navwalker
- Plugin URI:  https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
- Description: A custom WordPress nav walker class to implement the Bootstrap 4 navigation style in a custom theme using the WordPress built in menu manager.
- Author: Edward McIntyre - @twittem, WP Bootstrap, William Patton - @pattonwebz
- Version: 4.3.0
- Author URI: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap
- GitHub Plugin URI: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
- GitHub Branch: master
- License: GPL-3.0+
- License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
  */

// Check if Class Exists.
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker' ) ) :
/**
* WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker class.
*/
class WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

```
    /**
     * Whether the items_wrap contains schema microdata or not.
     *
     * @since 4.2.0
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $has_schema = false;

    /**
     * Ensure the items_wrap argument contains microdata.
     *
     * @since 4.2.0
     */
    public function __construct() {
        if ( ! has_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', array( $this, 'add_schema_to_navbar_ul' ) ) ) {
            add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', array( $this, 'add_schema_to_navbar_ul' ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since WP 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string           $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int              $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        // Default class to add to the file.
        $classes = array( 'dropdown-menu' );
        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since WP 4.8.0
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /*
         * The `.dropdown-menu` container needs to have a labelledby
         * attribute which points to it's trigger link.
         *
         * Form a string for the labelledby attribute from the the latest
         * link with an id that was added to the $output.
         */
        $labelledby = '';
        // Find all links with an id in the output.
        preg_match_all( '/(<a.*?id=\"|\')(.*?)\"|\'.*?>/im', $output, $matches );
        // With pointer at end of array check if we got an ID match.
        if ( end( $matches[2] ) ) {
            // Build a string to use as aria-labelledby.
            $labelledby = 'aria-labelledby="' . esc_attr( end( $matches[2] ) ) . '"';
        }
        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names $labelledby>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since WP 3.0.0
     * @since WP 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el()
     *
     * @param string           $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int              $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int              $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        if ( false !== strpos( $args->items_wrap, 'itemscope' ) && false === $this->has_schema ) {
            $this->has_schema  = true;
            $args->link_before = '<span itemprop="name">' . $args->link_before;
            $args->link_after .= '</span>';
        }

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        // Updating the CSS classes of a menu item in the WordPress Customizer preview results in all classes defined
        // in that particular input box to come in as one big class string.
        $split_on_spaces = function ( $class ) {
            return preg_split( '/\s+/', $class );
        };
        $classes         = $this->flatten( array_map( $split_on_spaces, $classes ) );

        /*
         * Initialize some holder variables to store specially handled item
         * wrappers and icons.
         */
        $linkmod_classes = array();
        $icon_classes    = array();

        /*
         * Get an updated $classes array without linkmod or icon classes.
         *
         * NOTE: linkmod and icon class arrays are passed by reference and
         * are maybe modified before being used later in this function.
         */
        $classes = self::separate_linkmods_and_icons_from_classes( $classes, $linkmod_classes, $icon_classes, $depth );

        // Join any icon classes plucked from $classes into a string.
        $icon_class_string = join( ' ', $icon_classes );

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since WP 4.4.0
         *
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int              $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         *
         * @var WP_Nav_Menu_Args
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        // Add .dropdown or .active classes where they are needed.
        if ( $this->has_children ) {
            $classes[] = 'dropdown';
        }
        if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes, true ) || in_array( 'current-menu-parent', $classes, true ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }

        // Add some additional default classes to the item.
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        $classes[] = 'nav-item';

        // Allow filtering the classes.
        $classes = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth );

        // Form a string of classes in format: class="class_names".
        $class_names = join( ' ', $classes );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since WP 3.0.1
         * @since WP 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string           $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item    The current menu item.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int              $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li ' . $id . $class_names . '>';

        // Initialize array for holding the $atts for the link item.
        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $item->target && empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener noreferrer';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
        }

        // If the item has_children add atts to <a>.
        if ( $this->has_children && $args->depth > 1 ) {
            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
            $atts['data-toggle']   = 'hover';
            $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
            $atts['aria-expanded'] = 'false';
            $atts['class']         = 'dropdown-toggle nav-link';
            $atts['id']            = 'menu-item-dropdown-' . $item->ID;
        } else {
            if ( true === $this->has_schema ) {
                $atts['itemprop'] = 'url';
            }

            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';



            // For items in dropdowns use .dropdown-item instead of .nav-link.
            if ( $depth > 0 ) {
                $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-item';
            } else {
                $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
            }
        }

        $atts['aria-current'] = $item->current ? 'page' : '';

        // Update atts of this item based on any custom linkmod classes.
        $atts = self::update_atts_for_linkmod_type( $atts, $linkmod_classes );

        // Allow filtering of the $atts array before using it.
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        // Build a string of html containing all the atts for the item.
        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        // Set a typeflag to easily test if this is a linkmod or not.
        $linkmod_type = self::get_linkmod_type( $linkmod_classes );

        // START appending the internal item contents to the output.
        $item_output = isset( $args->before ) ? $args->before : '';

        /*
         * This is the start of the internal nav item. Depending on what
         * kind of linkmod we have we may need different wrapper elements.
         */
        if ( '' !== $linkmod_type ) {
            // Is linkmod, output the required element opener.
            $item_output .= self::linkmod_element_open( $linkmod_type, $attributes );
        } else {
            // With no link mod type set this must be a standard <a> tag.
            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        }

        /*
         * Initiate empty icon var, then if we have a string containing any
         * icon classes form the icon markup with an <i> element. This is
         * output inside of the item before the $title (the link text).
         */
        $icon_html = '';
        if ( ! empty( $icon_class_string ) ) {
            // Append an <i> with the icon classes to what is output before links.
            $icon_html = '<i class="' . esc_attr( $icon_class_string ) . '" aria-hidden="true"></i> ';
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since WP 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string           $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Item $item  The current menu item.
         * @param WP_Nav_Menu_Args $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int              $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        // If the .sr-only class was set apply to the nav items text only.
        if ( in_array( 'sr-only', $linkmod_classes, true ) ) {
            $title         = self::wrap_for_screen_reader( $title );
            $keys_to_unset = array_keys( $linkmod_classes, 'sr-only', true );
            foreach ( $keys_to_unset as $k ) {
                unset( $linkmod_classes[ $k ] );
            }
        }

        // Put the item contents into $output.
        $item_output .= isset( $args->link_before ) ? $args->link_before . $icon_html . $title . $args->link_after : '';

        /*
         * This is the end of the internal nav item. We need to close the
         * correct element depending on the type of link or link mod.
         */
        if ( '' !== $linkmod_type ) {
            // Is linkmod, output the required closing element.
            $item_output .= self::linkmod_element_close( $linkmod_type );
        } else {
            // With no link mod type set this must be a standard <a> tag.
            $item_output .= '</a>';
        }

        $item_output .= isset( $args->after ) ? $args->after : '';

        // END appending the internal item contents to the output.
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Menu fallback.
     *
     * If this function is assigned to the wp_nav_menu's fallback_cb variable
     * and a menu has not been assigned to the theme location in the WordPress
     * menu manager the function will display nothing to a non-logged in user,
     * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if logged in as an admin.
     *
     * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu function.
     * @return string|void String when echo is false.
     */
    public static function fallback( $args ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Initialize var to store fallback html.
        $fallback_output = '';

        // Menu container opening tag.
        $show_container = false;
        if ( $args['container'] ) {
            /**
             * Filters the list of HTML tags that are valid for use as menu containers.
             *
             * @since WP 3.0.0
             *
             * @param array $tags The acceptable HTML tags for use as menu containers.
             *                    Default is array containing 'div' and 'nav'.
             */
            $allowed_tags = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', array( 'div', 'nav' ) );
            if ( is_string( $args['container'] ) && in_array( $args['container'], $allowed_tags, true ) ) {
                $show_container   = true;
                $class            = $args['container_class'] ? ' class="menu-fallback-container ' . esc_attr( $args['container_class'] ) . '"' : ' class="menu-fallback-container"';
                $id               = $args['container_id'] ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args['container_id'] ) . '"' : '';
                $fallback_output .= '<' . $args['container'] . $id . $class . '>';
            }
        }

        // The fallback menu.
        $class            = $args['menu_class'] ? ' class="menu-fallback-menu ' . esc_attr( $args['menu_class'] ) . '"' : ' class="menu-fallback-menu"';
        $id               = $args['menu_id'] ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args['menu_id'] ) . '"' : '';
        $fallback_output .= '<ul' . $id . $class . '>';
        $fallback_output .= '<li class="nav-item"><a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) . '" class="nav-link" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add a menu', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Add a menu', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) . '</a></li>';
        $fallback_output .= '</ul>';

        // Menu container closing tag.
        if ( $show_container ) {
            $fallback_output .= '</' . $args['container'] . '>';
        }

        // if $args has 'echo' key and it's true echo, otherwise return.
        if ( array_key_exists( 'echo', $args ) && $args['echo'] ) {
            // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
            echo $fallback_output;
        } else {
            return $fallback_output;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter to ensure the items_Wrap argument contains microdata.
     *
     * @since 4.2.0
     *
     * @param  array $args The nav instance arguments.
     * @return array $args The altered nav instance arguments.
     */
    public function add_schema_to_navbar_ul( $args ) {
        $wrap = $args['items_wrap'];
        if ( strpos( $wrap, 'SiteNavigationElement' ) === false ) {
            $args['items_wrap'] = preg_replace( '/(>).*>?\%3\$s/', ' itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"$0', $wrap );
        }

        return $args;
    }

    /**
     * Find any custom linkmod or icon classes and store in their holder
     * arrays then remove them from the main classes array.
     *
     * Supported linkmods: .disabled, .dropdown-header, .dropdown-divider, .sr-only
     * Supported iconsets: Font Awesome 4/5, Glypicons
     *
     * NOTE: This accepts the linkmod and icon arrays by reference.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param array   $classes         an array of classes currently assigned to the item.
     * @param array   $linkmod_classes an array to hold linkmod classes.
     * @param array   $icon_classes    an array to hold icon classes.
     * @param integer $depth           an integer holding current depth level.
     *
     * @return array  $classes         a maybe modified array of classnames.
     */
    private function separate_linkmods_and_icons_from_classes( $classes, &$linkmod_classes, &$icon_classes, $depth ) {
        // Loop through $classes array to find linkmod or icon classes.
        foreach ( $classes as $key => $class ) {
            /*
             * If any special classes are found, store the class in it's
             * holder array and and unset the item from $classes.
             */
            if ( preg_match( '/^disabled|^sr-only/i', $class ) ) {
                // Test for .disabled or .sr-only classes.
                $linkmod_classes[] = $class;
                unset( $classes[ $key ] );
            } elseif ( preg_match( '/^dropdown-header|^dropdown-divider|^dropdown-item-text/i', $class ) && $depth > 0 ) {
                /*
                 * Test for .dropdown-header or .dropdown-divider and a
                 * depth greater than 0 - IE inside a dropdown.
                 */
                $linkmod_classes[] = $class;
                unset( $classes[ $key ] );
            } elseif ( preg_match( '/^fa-(\S*)?|^fa(s|r|l|b)?(\s?)?$/i', $class ) ) {
                // Font Awesome.
                $icon_classes[] = $class;
                unset( $classes[ $key ] );
            } elseif ( preg_match( '/^glyphicon-(\S*)?|^glyphicon(\s?)$/i', $class ) ) {
                // Glyphicons.
                $icon_classes[] = $class;
                unset( $classes[ $key ] );
            }
        }

        return $classes;
    }

    /**
     * Return a string containing a linkmod type and update $atts array
     * accordingly depending on the decided.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param array $linkmod_classes array of any link modifier classes.
     *
     * @return string                empty for default, a linkmod type string otherwise.
     */
    private function get_linkmod_type( $linkmod_classes = array() ) {
        $linkmod_type = '';
        // Loop through array of linkmod classes to handle their $atts.
        if ( ! empty( $linkmod_classes ) ) {
            foreach ( $linkmod_classes as $link_class ) {
                if ( ! empty( $link_class ) ) {

                    // Check for special class types and set a flag for them.
                    if ( 'dropdown-header' === $link_class ) {
                        $linkmod_type = 'dropdown-header';
                    } elseif ( 'dropdown-divider' === $link_class ) {
                        $linkmod_type = 'dropdown-divider';
                    } elseif ( 'dropdown-item-text' === $link_class ) {
                        $linkmod_type = 'dropdown-item-text';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $linkmod_type;
    }

    /**
     * Update the attributes of a nav item depending on the limkmod classes.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param array $atts            array of atts for the current link in nav item.
     * @param array $linkmod_classes an array of classes that modify link or nav item behaviors or displays.
     *
     * @return array                 maybe updated array of attributes for item.
     */
    private function update_atts_for_linkmod_type( $atts = array(), $linkmod_classes = array() ) {
        if ( ! empty( $linkmod_classes ) ) {
            foreach ( $linkmod_classes as $link_class ) {
                if ( ! empty( $link_class ) ) {
                    /*
                     * Update $atts with a space and the extra classname
                     * so long as it's not a sr-only class.
                     */
                    if ( 'sr-only' !== $link_class ) {
                        $atts['class'] .= ' ' . esc_attr( $link_class );
                    }
                    // Check for special class types we need additional handling for.
                    if ( 'disabled' === $link_class ) {
                        // Convert link to '#' and unset open targets.
                        $atts['href'] = '#';
                        unset( $atts['target'] );
                    } elseif ( 'dropdown-header' === $link_class || 'dropdown-divider' === $link_class || 'dropdown-item-text' === $link_class ) {
                        // Store a type flag and unset href and target.
                        unset( $atts['href'] );
                        unset( $atts['target'] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $atts;
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the passed text in a screen reader only class.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param string $text the string of text to be wrapped in a screen reader class.
     * @return string      the string wrapped in a span with the class.
     */
    private function wrap_for_screen_reader( $text = '' ) {
        if ( $text ) {
            $text = '<span class="sr-only">' . $text . '</span>';
        }
        return $text;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the correct opening element and attributes for a linkmod.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param string $linkmod_type a sting containing a linkmod type flag.
     * @param string $attributes   a string of attributes to add to the element.
     *
     * @return string              a string with the openign tag for the element with attribibutes added.
     */
    private function linkmod_element_open( $linkmod_type, $attributes = '' ) {
        $output = '';
        if ( 'dropdown-item-text' === $linkmod_type ) {
            $output .= '<span class="dropdown-item-text"' . $attributes . '>';
        } elseif ( 'dropdown-header' === $linkmod_type ) {
            /*
             * For a header use a span with the .h6 class instead of a real
             * header tag so that it doesn't confuse screen readers.
             */
            $output .= '<span class="dropdown-header h6"' . $attributes . '>';
        } elseif ( 'dropdown-divider' === $linkmod_type ) {
            // This is a divider.
            $output .= '<div class="dropdown-divider"' . $attributes . '>';
        }
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Return the correct closing tag for the linkmod element.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param string $linkmod_type a string containing a special linkmod type.
     *
     * @return string              a string with the closing tag for this linkmod type.
     */
    private function linkmod_element_close( $linkmod_type ) {
        $output = '';
        if ( 'dropdown-header' === $linkmod_type || 'dropdown-item-text' === $linkmod_type ) {
            /*
             * For a header use a span with the .h6 class instead of a real
             * header tag so that it doesn't confuse screen readers.
             */
            $output .= '</span>';
        } elseif ( 'dropdown-divider' === $linkmod_type ) {
            // This is a divider.
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Flattens a multidimensional array to a simple array.
     *
     * @param array $array a multidimensional array.
     *
     * @return array a simple array
     */
    public function flatten( $array ) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ( $array as $element ) {
            if ( is_array( $element ) ) {
                array_push( $result, ...$this->flatten( $element ) );
            } else {
                $result[] = $element;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

endif;

this is my code in function.php

```
    // nav-walker.........................................................

function register_navwalker()
{
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker');

if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php')) {
    // File does not exist... return an error.
    return new WP_Error('class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker-missing', __('It appears the class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php file may be missing.', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker'));
} else {
    // File exists... require it.
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}

register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'webramz'),
    'footer' => __('footer Menu', 'webramz'),
));




add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'bootstrap5_dropdown_fix');
function bootstrap5_dropdown_fix($atts)
{
    if (array_key_exists('data-toggle', $atts)) {
        unset($atts['data-toggle']);
        $atts['data-bs-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    }
    return $atts;
}


add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'bootstrap5_hover_fix');
function bootstrap5_hover_fix($atts)
{
    if (array_key_exists('data-toggle', $atts)) {
        unset($atts['data-toggle']);
        $atts['data-bs-toggle'] = 'hover';
    }
    return $atts;
}
```

this is my code in header.php

```
<nav class="py-0 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light d-none d-lg-block">

                <?php wp_nav_menu([
                  'menu' => 'primary',
                  'theme_location' => 'primary',
                  'container' => 'div',
                  'container_id' => 'navbarNav',
                  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                  'menu_id' => false,
                  'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav pe-0',
                  'depth' => 5,
                  'fallback_cb' => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                  'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
                ]); ?>

              </nav>
```

Comment: Share your code so we can help.

Comment: So you are using plugin not your own navwalker. To simplify it you need to pass the proper classes and attributes required by bs5 to work. You can look into this as starting point - https://github.com/AlexWebLab/bootstrap-5-wordpress-navbar-walker